# Change source of a query using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to figure out How to edit the Source of a query automatically via VBA, which creates the query. The Point is that the excel file containing the Data is Stored in the Same folder As the excel file in which the query will be created, and if i want to Send the whole folder to another Person, the query tries to connect to My User instead of the local excel file containing the Data.

```
 Dim Datei2 As String
Set Datei2 = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Datei2 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\NameOfTheFile.csv"
'This part creates the path I want to use

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="NameOfTheFile" _
    , Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Quelle = 

Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\censored\NameOfTheFile.c 
sv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=18, Encoding=1252, 
 QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Geänderter Typ"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}," & _
    " {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", type t" & _
    "ext}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Geänderter Typ"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""NameOfTheFile"";Extended Properti" _
    , "es="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT * FROM [NameOfTheFile]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "NameOfTheFile"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Hope it's not too messy, i created a new Macro and included all the code, so you can run it if you enter the Paths and Filenames.

I created the first three lines of code which give me the location of the excel containing the data, which should then be pasted five lines below where the current absolute path is (under CSV.Document(File.Contents(...)

Or is it possible to edit an existing query where i can change the path using a string like above?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You already have the answer in your own code: ActiveWorkbook.Path Personally I would define the actual workbook not just any old active workbook with: Application.ThisWorkbook.Path. just reference this to get your folder location.

Comment: Building off-of @5202456's answer, you can append data variables into strings like-so:  `"This string " & variableName & " has a variable."`

Comment: @5202456 Yeah, I have the Path created, but I cant put it in the field where the current absolute Path is

Comment: @DasGuy Have you tried using: `Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & Datei2 & """)` instead of: `Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\censored\NameOfTheFile.csv"")` ?

Comment: @Mistella Thank you, this works! I'm curious, why the need for the extra characters? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @DasGuy Since I felt the explanation would be rather long, and since it's helpful for posts to have accepted answers (instead of just solved in the comments), I posted the answer w/ explanation. If it's not clear, or I didn't completely answer your question, please feel free to ask in the comments on that answer. (You _could_ also ask in the comments on the question, but that can get confusing sometimes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extracted from comment:**

---

For the section of the string that says:

```
Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\censored\NameOfTheFile.csv"")
```

Instead use teh below where `Datei2` is the string variable with the new file path:

```
Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & Datei2 & """)
```

---

**Explanation**

The reason for using `Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & Datei2 & """)` instead of `Csv.Document(File.Contents(" & Datei2 & ")`.

You can see from the original line of code (shown below) three different uses of the `"`.

1. Single `"`:

   - This marks either the beginning or the ending of a string. When appending strings together, these single double-quotes are not included within the string value. They are simple markers for Excel to know where the boundaries of a string are located.
2. Double `""`:

   - This is used within a string to store the value of `"` since a single double-quote on its own would be interpreted as a string boundary, not a value to be included within the string.
3. Triple `"""`:

   - This is a combination of the two above. You would primarily see this at either the very beginning or very end of a hard-coded string value; i.e. the last hard-coded string value at the end of the code below (`"    #""Geänderter Typ"""`). The value actually being stored is :`#"Geänderter Typ"` (although the tab space before the `#` is not showing). The first `"` indicates the beginning of the string. The `""` directly after the `#` is interpreted as a single double-quote character to store as part of the string. The `"""` at the end is interpreted as first a `"` character to store, then the end boundary of the string.
   - If the `"""` had been at the beginning of the string, it would have been interpreted as first the strating boundary of the string, then a `"` character to store.

Since the original section of the string addressed in the answer (`Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\censored\NameOfTheFile.csv""`) is part of a hard-coded string, the `""` is indicating a stored `"` within the string.

Since that stored `"` needed to be included for the code to work correctly, and since the `Datei2` variable did not contain stored `"`'s on either end, the `"""` were required to maintain the stored `"` within the string on either side of the `Datei2` variable.

---

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="NameOfTheFile", Formula:= "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "    Quelle = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\censored\NameOfTheFile.csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=18, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "    #""Geänderter Typ"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{""Column1"", type text},{""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text},{""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text},{""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text},{""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text},{""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text},{""Column18"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Geänderter Typ"""
```